# vim backspace not working normally

Tags: vim, key-mapping

The <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key is not working as expected in `vim` and also in `vi`. It is working as the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, and Delete key is deleting the char, but instead something wierd happens. But, for now, I am trying to get the `Backspace` key working.

I tried few solution by googling and searching unix.se, but none helped. I tried adding

```
:map~ ^? ^H
```

to `.exrc` file. Also tried adding following function from [this link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems), later mapping the correct key-sequence as given, but even that didn't help solve the issue.

```
func Backspace()
  if col('.') == 1
    if line('.')  != 1
      return  "\<ESC>kA\<Del>"
    else
      return ""
    endif
  else
    return "\<Left>\<Del>"
  endif
endfunc
```

#### `vim` details

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Jun 12 2009 07:09:20)
```

#### Machine

```
$ cat /etc/*release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
```

#### Note:

1. I connect to a remote unix machine using putty connection manager.
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> works as normal `Backspace` key works i.e. delete a character to the left.

Comment: Is it in command mode or in insert mode? At times, it helps configuring PuTTY as follows: "Keyboard" tab: Function keys set to "Linux". "Connection data" tab: "Terminal-type string" set to `linux`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Gert's comment about PuTTY, the third post in [this thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/backspace-becomes-in-putty-td1194857.html) also has a note about PuTTY settings:

> Under the Terminal -> Keyboard section, there is block labelled
>   "change the sequences sent by:" - the 1st one is Backspace. It should
>   be either Control-H or Control-?. Change it to the opposite of what is
>   currently set and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the backspace mode?  Have a look at `:help bs` and try the following:

```
set bs=indent,eol,start
```

There's also a note in that help section about using `:fixdel` "if your <BS> or <Del> key does not do what you want".

You may also need to set "no compatible" (WRT to vi), so `:set nocp`.

Comment: Yup tried that also. `backspace` still working as `delete` key.

Comment: Hmm, how about with `:set nocp` too?

Answer (score 0):

[goldilocks answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60079/17265) helped, and after setting the config as he showed, I followed the following steps that solved the problem -

Setting the `TERM` to xterm by

```
$ TERM=xterm; export TERM
```

And later adding the following to `.bashrc` file.

```
stty erase ^H
```